# Using AWS SQS with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I am unable to find any example on how to Use Amazon AWS SQS service in conjunction with Ruby on Rails.

Please could someone provide a simple, barebones example of using SQS to send email.

Comment: to send email? SQS is a queueing service, although of course the entities processing the queue could be doing anything with the results they receive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may look into these examples. I have taken this from the GitHub GIST - [AWS SQS Example](https://gist.github.com/seratch/3951664).

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'yaml'
require 'aws-sdk'

config_file = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__),"config.yml")
config = YAML.load(File.read(config_file))
AWS.config(config)

# http://rubydoc.info/github/amazonwebservices/aws-sdk-for-ruby/master/AWS/SQS

sqs = AWS::SQS.new
queue = sqs.queues.create("my_queue")

# http://rubydoc.info/github/amazonwebservices/aws-sdk-for-ruby/master/AWS/SQS/Queue

send = lambda { |name, queue|
  while true do
    queue.send_message("#{name}:#{Time.now.to_s}")
    sleep 1
  end
}

Thread.new { send.call("t1", queue) }
Thread.new { send.call("t2", queue) }
Thread.new { send.call("t3", queue) }

sleep 1000
```

Answer (score 6):

You may check [Shoryuken](https://github.com/phstc/shoryuken#rails-integration), it's integrated with SQS and Rails (ActiveJob). But you can also use it without Rails, in a standalone Ruby app.